# How can I change this Breadth First Search code so that it works?

Tags: java

Edit 1: Additional Information 
The goal of this code is to run through a tree, with no value. It will then output the results of the search (which should be the entire tree). If any additional information is needed, let me know!

I honestly don't really know what I am doing. I was trying to follow this picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwJrj.png

Any help is appreciated.

```
public static <T> void BFS(TreeNode<T> t, int root){

    ArrayList<Integer> S = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Queue<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    S.add(root);
    Q.add(root);

    while (!Q.isEmpty()){
        Q.remove();
    }
    for (TreeNode n : t.getChildren()) {
        if (!S.contains(n)) {
            S.add(n);
            Q.add(n);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide textual information as text, not as an external link to a picture of text. That way even with beginners reputation, you can make all info needed for helping you available conveniently to potential answerers.

Comment: A quick glance at your picture shows that in contrast to your shown codeit is using a `current` variable and does something important with it in the line `for ...`. Note that I now could quote that line, if it were not a picture...

Comment: Provided additional info. Should I try to be more detailed with it or have I provided an adequate amount now?

Comment: Let me repeat: Please provide textual information as text, not as an external link to a picture of text.

Comment: You could make a [mcve], including a hard coded tree to demonstrate in which way it does not act as expected. Then describe how it does act in contrast to how it should act.

Comment: Consider phrasing your question as one readable text, not as a puzzle of information which makes people first stumble over later added information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a working version of your algorithm here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class BreadthFirstSearch {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //just for testing
        new BreadthFirstSearch();
    }
    
    public BreadthFirstSearch() {
        //build a TreeNode<T> graph for testing
        TreeNode<Integer> root = new TreeNode<Integer>(1);
        
        TreeNode<Integer> child_1 = new TreeNode<Integer>(2);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_2 = new TreeNode<Integer>(3);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_1_1 = new TreeNode<Integer>(4);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_1_2 = new TreeNode<Integer>(5);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_2_1 = new TreeNode<Integer>(6);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_2_2 = new TreeNode<Integer>(7);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_1_2_1 = new TreeNode<Integer>(8);
        TreeNode<Integer> child_2_2_1 = new TreeNode<Integer>(9);
        
        child_1.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child_1_1, child_1_2));
        child_2.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child_2_1, child_2_2));
        child_1_2.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child_1_2_1));
        child_2_2.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child_2_2_1));
        root.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child_1, child_2));
        
        //now root is a graph like this:
        
        //              1
        //           /     \
        //          2       3
        //         /  \    /  \
        //        4   5   6    7
        //           /        /
        //          8        9
        
        //so the breadth first search should lead to the result list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        List<Integer> breadthFirstSearched = BFS(root);
        System.out.println(breadthFirstSearched);
    }
    
    /**
     * A simple TreeNode<T> implementation.
     */
    public class TreeNode<T> {
        
        private List<TreeNode<T>> children;
        private T value;
        
        public TreeNode(T value) {
            children = new ArrayList<TreeNode<T>>();
            this.value = value;
        }
        
        public List<TreeNode<T>> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }
        public void setChildren(List<TreeNode<T>> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }
        
        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
    
    public static <T> List<T> BFS(TreeNode<T> root) {//here you just need the root node which also holds the graph in this implementation
        List<T> S = new ArrayList<T>();//here you should use the generic type T (if the TreeNode<T> is a TreeNode<Integer> it will be a List<Integer> on runtime)
        Queue<TreeNode<T>> Q = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();//here you need a queue of TreeNode<T> objects instead of integers
        
        S.add(root.getValue());
        Q.add(root);
        
        //this would just remove all elements from the queue before starting the real algorithm
        /*while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
            Q.remove();
        }*/
        
        //in the pseudocode you provided the code after the while was indented, which means it belongs inside the while loop like this:
        while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
            //here you need to get the first TreeNode<T> from the queue
            TreeNode<T> current = Q.poll();//poll is equal to dequeue here (both get the first element of the queue and remove it from the queue)
            for (TreeNode<T> n : current.getChildren()) {//iterate over all children of the current node
                if (!S.contains(n.getValue())) {//here you need to check the value of n (otherwise you compare TreeNode<T> to T which doesn't make much sense)
                    S.add(n.getValue());
                    Q.add(n);
                }
            }
        }
        
        //here you should return the created list, otherwise it's no longer available
        return S;
    }
}
```

Since you didn't provide the class TreeNode I implemented one as I thought it would probably work. I also added a test case so you can run the example and see it works. The output the program generates is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] like expedted.

The code iterates through the tree and finds the "higher" nodes first. A good example on how it works is here:

[image: Breadth first search gif from wikipedia]

The black nodes are the one that are already added to the tree, the gray ones are added to the queue but not the tree and the white ones are not yet added to the list nor the tree.

A full explenation of the algorithm can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)